# Can't look up multiple lines of text columns when creating a workflow in SharePoint Designer 2013

Tags: list, designer-workflow

I'm trying to create a workflow in SharePoint Designer 2013 that updates information in one list (a custom list) when information in another (a task list) changes.

The custom list (called 'Documentation register') is used to keep track of documentation for a particular product. It has a multiple lines of text column called 'Revision history.

The task list (called 'Tasks') is used to assign documentation-related tasks to team members. It has a multiple lines of text column called 'Revision required.'

When someone assigns a revision (by describing the kind of revision needed in the Tasks list > 'Revision required' column), I would like the text in that column to be appended to the 'Revision history' column in the 'Documentation register' list.

I tried using the Update List Item action in Designer but haven't had any luck so far. Although the lists themselves appear as lookup choices, neither of the columns do. I assume that's because you can't lookup multiple-lines-of-text columns?

Is there *any* way to make those columns appear as update options?

Thanks so much in advance.